# Tcl Timer Snippet

Tags: tcl

I need to print out countdown timer for the time my script sleeps.

Screen output looks like this -

```
Started Script

Script will Sleep for 100 seconds

Time left 100
Time left 99
Time left 98
```

I want print the Time left but by erasing the previous entry.

**at time 0**

```
Started Script

Script will Sleep for 100 seconds

Time left 100
```

**at time 1**

```
Started Script

Script will Sleep for 100 seconds

Time left 99
```

**at time 2**

```
Started Script

Script will Sleep for 100 seconds

Time left 98
```

How can I do this in tcl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is with some terminal tricks. The key trick is that printing a carriage return (`\u000d` or `\r`) sends the cursor back to the start of the current line.

```
puts "Started Script\n"

# Turn off output buffering; important!
fconfigure stdout -buffering none

puts "Script will sleep for 100 seconds\n"

set deadline [expr {[clock seconds] + 100}]
while 1 {
    set now [clock seconds]
    if {$deadline <= $now} {
        break
    }

    # Tricky; the CR is critical to making this work...
    puts -nonewline "\rTime left [expr {$deadline - $now}] "

    # Sleep *half* a second for accuracy
    after 500
}

# Blank the countdown line and put a finished message with a cheap hack
puts -nonewline "[string repeat " " 15]\rDone!"
```

You can get a more accurate countdown by using `clock milliseconds` as your timing source and shortening the sleep in `after`; you'll need some (small amount of) extra work to convert the time remaining to seconds in that case.